# GridSearchCV with n_jobs = -1 kernel Restarts

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter, anaconda3

I'm running a Jupyter Notebook in a Azure machine with the following settings :

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
- Memory: 64Gb
- Number of cores: 16
- Anaconda Environment
- Architecture:        x86_64
- CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
- Byte Order:          Little Endian
- CPU(s):              16
- On-line CPU(s) list: 0-15
- Thread(s) per core:  2
- Core(s) per socket:  8
- Socket(s):           1
- NUMA node(s):        2
- Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
- CPU family:          23
- Model:               49
- Model name:          AMD EPYC 7452 32-Core Processor
- Stepping:            0
- CPU MHz:             2345.605
- BogoMIPS:            4691.21
- Hypervisor vendor:   Microsoft
- Virtualization type: full
- L1d cache:           32K
- L1i cache:           32K
- L2 cache:            512K
- L3 cache:            16384K
- NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7
- NUMA node1 CPU(s):   8-15

I'm trying to launch a GridSearchCV like this:

```
# DecissionTreeClassifier
arbol = DTC()
grid_arbol = {"max_depth":list(range(5,15)),
                "class_weight":["balanced"]}
gs_arbol = GridSearchCV(arbol,
                        grid_arbol,
                        cv=2,
                        scoring=scoring,
                        verbose=4,
                        n_jobs=-1) # -1 should use all cores (16)
grid_search.fit(X_training, y_training)
```

Once I launch this code, Kernel restarts. I have to change the n_jobs=8 (half of the total cores) to launch correctly this GridSearchCV.

The question is that I would like to use all CPU cores (and all the run memory), but I don't find the clue to use them from Ubuntu.

Is there any OS/Jupyter/Python/Anaconda option to launch with all n_jobs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you aren't running out of memory when using all cores? You can take a quick look using `dmesg` to see if a process was killed because you ran out of memory

Comment: Yes you're right, it is because there is a running out of memory, but the thing is that when I launch GridSearch with 8 jobs, the memory goes down to the minimum and later, halts in 32GB used, leaving free around 32GB.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when searching for a solution for what seems to be the same problem I'm having when fitting a LassoCV. Whenever I specify `n_jobs=-1` I get a kernel crash. I'm using VS Code with Jupyter extension on a 2018 6-core i7 MacBook Pro. Everything is cool when I use `n_jobs=5` or less.

I found this resource that seems to explain the problem.

[Why do I sometime get a crash/freeze with n_jobs > 1 under OSX or Linux?](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html)